# Replacement for Facebook feature "imported stories"

Tags: facebook, rss

What is a good replacement for the Facebook feature "imported stories" that allowed you to import content from other sites like RSS Feeds, Picasa, Google Reader etc. Facebook recently disabled the feature with this message:

> The Imported Stories feature is no
>   longer available. Most of the sites
>   supported by this feature now allow
>   you to publish stories to Facebook
>   directly from the site.

I used this feature to have my Livejournal blog updates and Picasa photos automatically post on my wall. How can I do that now? Despite the advice from Facebook, I can't find way to do this directly from either Livejournal or Picasa.

Answer (score 1):

i'm having the same issue......... i don't know why they change that... and without any notification. As regards to your feeds blog you can add the site url in the "import" from you're notes.. so as to bring the new posts automatically from your blog.

Comment: Nice catch. For my Livejournal blog, the import notes is working fine. Now, I just need to find a way to update Picasa. I too am annoyed the Facebook pulled this feature without any notification. It just stopped working and I had to search around to find out what happened.